Derivative of Multivariable Function of Random Variables (as functions of time) with respect to Time
Consider the following function:
$$
F(t, X, Y)=V(t)\cdot W(X, Y)^{\alpha}
$$
Where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables that change continuously over time $t$. Function $W(X,Y)$ is function of those two random variables. $V(t)$ is a single variable function of time. Parameter $\alpha$ is a constant.

If we know that $V$ is differentiable, how can we find derivative of $F$ with respect to $t$?


I have tried differentiating using product rule and basic chain rule:
$$
\frac{d F}{d t}=\frac{dV}{dt}W(X,Y)^{\alpha} + V\frac{d}{dt}\left[W(X, Y)^{\alpha}\right] = \frac{dV}{dt}W(X, Y)^{\alpha} + \alpha V\cdot W(X, Y)^{\alpha - 1}\frac{d W}{dt}
$$
And that's where I've stuck. I know something like chain rule can be used for $\frac{d W}{d t}$, but how can we even find derivative of random variable? Does it even make sense to talk about rate of change of something that changes randomly?
Context
This function comes from (still developing) game (modification), and it describes "energy conversion" model. $F$ is amount of converted energy in $t$ seconds. Function $V(t)$ volume of inputted substance in $t$ seconds. It is described as a functions, because there are different ways to realize an input. Function $W(X,Y)^{\alpha}$ is an instability function where each random variable has some probability density depending on both nature of conversion $(X)$ and environment $(Y)$ where conversion happens. Rule for $W$ depends of which Device is used for conversion. Device takes some volume of substance and turns into energy. In stable case and neutral environment $X$ and $Y$ are constants. However, in most cases they are random and have a small interval of values they can get with certain probability described by function. Derivative of $F$ with respect to time should give general rate of conversion for any "situation". More specifically, its expected value.

If you want to model that the random variables $X,Y$ change over time then they should carry a $t$ as an argument. Suggestion: $X_t,Y_t,.$ On top of that they are random: $X_t(\omega),Y_t(\omega),.$ What comes next is that you should tell us how exactly $X_t,Y_t$ depend on time $t,.$ Through a non differentiable Brownian motion? In that case the Ito formula applies which I won't repeat here as it can be found in the standard literature. Or are $X_t(\omega),Y_t(\omega)$ differentiable w.r.t time? In that case, for each $\omega$ the standard chain rule from calculus applies.

Needless to say that other processes than Brownian motion are conceivable. The standard ones (say Poisson process) have a generalized version of the Ito formula.
